# JsonResults and Execution Order of GET POST

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out someone else's code. This is MVC 4.0 and the call to this ActionResult never has a start or end date. Never. So it fires getCalVm which as you can grock builds the view model going back to to the View. However on it's way back this JsonResult (below the ActionResult) captures the code execution path and flattens  the returned view model calling the exact same view model but now wrapping it in today's date + or - 2 months.

What's odd is this Calendar ActionResult isn't defined as a mapped route in Global.asax that's contrary to everything I've read about Routes. I can find definitions for the JsonResult routes GetEventsByEntity and two others. See the full route definitions below.

Can someone tell me if there is a route defined that maps to /School/Calendar/EntityID that would get this URL www.domain.com/school/calendar/10001 and which route it is?

Finally, execution order. Why are the JsonResult routes firing after the ActionResult? Can I put a test condition in the JsonResults that informs them the view is built already and they should drop execution. Something like using a Session variable that notifies the JsonResult look, we have data stop execution. What's the right way to properly coerce this execution of code. The previous developer is taking cards in the unemployment line so I am unsure what he intended with this mess. If someone with a touch more experience than I can interpret man I'm all ears.

Lastly, how would I call this action result from an onclick in the client side? More specifically would that be the right way to do it? I'm feeding the view back to this 3rd party calendar and maybe there's a better way. http://fullcalendar.io/ sorry for the deluge but I think this code sucks and I cannot make sense of it. So either I'm right and need to fix this or I'm stupid. I'm okay with being stupid, admitting it is the only way to correct that flaw.

Also, if there's a way to use Ajax and load the previous and next month for the io calendar I'd like to know how. I'm not asking someone to write the code although I'd certainly thank them for it. But the URL to the calendar has docs. If someone who understand Ajax and javascript better than I (which is just about anyone taller than 3 feet) can help, toss a link or something I'll buy the beer in this life or the next.

```
    public ActionResult Calendar(int? id, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        SetSchoolIdCookie(id);
        return View(getCalVm(id, startDate, endDate));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult GetEventsByEntity(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        if (!startDate.HasValue) { startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2); }
        if (!endDate.HasValue) { endDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(2); }
        return Json(getCalVm(null, startDate.Value, endDate.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here's the route maps:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
        "GameRoute", // Route name
        "Teams/Game/{id}/{entityId}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Teams", action = "Game", id = UrlParameter.Optional, entityId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "TournamentRoute", // Route name
        "Teams/Tournament/{id}/{entityId}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Teams", action = "Tournament", id = UrlParameter.Optional, entityId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "SchoolStateSearch", // Route name
        "School/StateSearch", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "School", action = "StateSearch" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "SchoolSearch", // Route name
        "School/Search", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "School", action = "Search" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "SchoolCalendarJson", // Route name
          "School/GetEventsByEntity", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "School", action = "GetEventsByEntity" } // Parameter defaults
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "SchoolCalendarJsonSummary", // Route name
          "School/GetSummaryEventsByEntity", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "School", action = "GetSummaryEventsByEntity" } // Parameter defaults
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "SchoolCalendarJsonDetails", // Route name
          "School/GetDetailEventsByEntity", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "School", action = "GetDetailEventsByEntity" } // Parameter defaults
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "School", // Route name
          "School/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "School", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "School", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(VS.98).aspx) for a basic understanding of ASP.NET MVC controllers and routes.

A GET request to this address:

```
www.domain.com/School/Calendar/10001
```

will utilize this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                
    new { controller = "School", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and will hit this endpoint:

```
public ActionResult Calendar(int? id, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    SetSchoolIdCookie(id);
    return View(getCalVm(id, startDate, endDate));
}
```

Since FullCalendar appears to be a jQuery plugin, I would use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).